# When to use State Machines - FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, state-machines

I've read a lot about FSMs (Finite State Machines) when doing VHDL tutorials. They are easy and I've used them a lot but I still don't understand something and can't find the answer online:

When should I use FSMs (Moore or Mealy) in my VHDL design?

For example, if I implement an algorithm (previously in C language) in VHDL, shall I use an FSM?

Comment: If an algorithm is describable as an FSM of an acceptable size, use FSM as it is extremely descriptive, uniform and easily analyzable representation. BTW, I am using FSMs a lot in C as well.

Comment: use them when you have states to consider. most of my python code makes use of FSM as it is a nice concise way to capture what is happening and when

Comment: They're the most sensible way to do control flow for multi-cycle operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to split an operation across multiple clock cycles, you have two options : pipelining, and sequencing

Let's consider a mythical operation consisting of four multiplications , for example - where each multiplication (except the first) requires the output of the previous multiplication as one of its inputs. However the basic ideas are much more general.

In pipelining, you have enough hardware to perform every operation simultaneously, interconnected by pipeline registers. This implies four multipliers, separated by pipeline registers.  It will take 4 clock cycles to get the first result (so we say the pipeline is 4 stages deep, and the latency is 4 cycles) but then you get a new result every clock cycle (so we say the throughput rate is 1 cycle). [A little more info on pipeline design...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765205/how-can-i-speed-up-my-math-operations-in-vhdl/14777458#14777458)

Downside : this is a large piece of hardware - 4 multipliers are relatively expensive (which is why some FPGA families offer many small multipliers as highly optimised blocks).

The alternative is to sequence each operation in the same multiplier, giving a much smaller design, but delivering a result every 4 cycles.

In this case you can use a single multiplier, storing its result in a single register, for a much smaller design.

Every 4th cycle (or whenever something else signals a new input in ready) you connect the new input to one input port of the multiplier; in other cycles you feed that port from the output register (to use the previous multiply result). And in every cycle you feed the appropriate data (filter coefficients, matrix values, whatever) into the other multiplier port. Four cycles later, you present the final result as your output, and signal to your consumer that a new result is ready.

The obvious way to sequence these operations is a state machine (FSM).

Indeed the computations can be embedded in the actions associated with each state, for example:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
   Done <= '0';   -- and any other default actions
   case state is
   when Idle =>
      if Start = '1' then
         Temp  := Input * C1;
         State := S1;
      end if;
   when s1 =>
      Temp  := Temp * C2;
      State := S2;
   when s2 =>
      Temp  := Temp * C3;
      State := S3;
   when s3 =>
      Temp  := Temp * C4;
      State := S4;
   when s4 =>
      Output <= Temp;
      Done   <= '1';
      State  := Idle;
      -- optional alternative for bombproof handshaking
      -- if Start = '0' then
      --    Done <= '1';
      --    State <= Idle;
      -- end if;
   end case;
end if;
```

If you are interacting with other units - SPI interfaces, UARTs etc, the FSM is again usually the best method.

Answer (score 3):

In FPGA design, there are two major classes of operations:

- Combinatorics, in other words, implementing logical *expressions*.
- Clocked operations, in other words, hooking up to latches (for instance D-type flip flops), or in programming terms; implementing *sequences of operations*.

As you may know, there is a limit to how large your combinatoric circuits can be. Each logic gate has a time-delay, if the input signal rises from "0" to "1", it will take time for the output to be stabilize to the correct answer. If you cascade it too far, you will find that the output can be out of sync, producing errors.

The solution to this is of course to rely on latches. At a particular time, you sample the output, keeping it valid until next time. This is where clocked operations enter the picture.

*Pipelining* follows naturally from this. If you can't do everything in once cycle, then split it in into more parts, where each part feeds the partial result to the next part. The final part presents the final result, usually N cycles later.

But, sometimes it is not as simple as that. If the problem requires something different to happen depending on a state (typically *time*, or some external inputs), then *Finite State Machines* (FSM) is the most logical solution.

FSMs reduce logical complexity. *"When this and that happens, we should do this."* Examples are in order, but consider that the execution of a CPU is actually just a giant state machine.

As a general rule, if you can break down your problem into a finite number of steps where the *transition from one step to another is potentially varying*, then you want to consider using a FSM. Since this is by far the most common scenario, you will find that you will be using FSMs quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would give an opposite answer. When not to use a FSM ?

If your sequence of operations need more than around 30 states, you are probably either :

- Trying to mix in one state the behaviour of several machines. For example, in a serial protocol, generating the bits out of bytes can be done by a FSM, assembling bytes to generate frames by another.
- Writing software, the state machine should be typically replaced by microcode.

Answer (score 0):

Nontrivial digital systems which are almost always synchronous and thus use a clock can be thought of as a line of registers that latch data with combinatorial logic in between them that processes the data. The data is represented by binary signals. This line that may be a single line or branch out to other lines, is described as a data path. The data flows in this path and is processed via boolean operations implemented via combinatorial logic, the intermediate results are stored into the register and then processed by the next lump of combinatorial logic. This is also how  "pipeline" looks like.

We need a state machine to basically control this flow of data i.e we make decisions based on intermediate results on how to progress the data, does it continue in a linear fashion, does it get branched, does it get deleted or overwritten, do we get a new input value, do we save the output value and send a signal telling the other part of hardware that the data processing in this part of hardware is complete or to request new data from other part of the design; These things are straight forward to write in a high level language. In VHDL where we describe hardware, we create a state machine to do this.

What I have given is a very general description that may not make complete sense. It will make sense when you actually design a system where you need to use it.